# Open FirebaseUI-Android with Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebaseui

When I try to open FirebaseUI-Android with Android Studio nothing happens.

I use Android studio 3.1.3. I want to see demos there.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android.git

I have tried to open app project but nothing happens. All views show a message that said "Nothing to show".

Someone have opened this project with android studio? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did:

1. Download latest version of gradle from https://gradle.org/
2. Open Android project and choose only app folder
3. Select my gradle folder when assistant asked me
4. Put google-services.json on the app project

Now it is working.

Comment: It doesn't help me. Have you done anything else as well. anything related Gradle-Kotlin

Comment: Nothing else. After download gradle (put on a folder) and open app project and select gradle folder when assistant asked me, everything started to working fine in my case.